# Adding to list with Bloc (flutter)

Tags: flutter, dart, bloc, state-management

I've just started learning how to manage state with BLOC in flutter.
I've written this small and simple example (With Cubit) that is supposed to add names to a list and remove from it.
The list does not get filled and I cannot figure out where the problem is.

My code:

```
class StudentHandlerCubit extends Cubit<StudentHandlerState> {
  ///initial value is set here:
  StudentHandlerCubit() : super(StudentHandlerState(badSts: []));

  addToBadSts(String name) {
    state.badSts.add(name);
    return emit(StudentHandlerState(badSts: state.badSts));
  }

  void removeFromBadSts(String name){
    state.badSts.removeWhere((element) => element==name);
    return emit(StudentHandlerState(badSts: state.badSts));
  }

}
```

```
class StudentHandlerState{
  ///Sts = Students
  List<String> badSts = [];
  StudentHandlerState({badSts=const []});
}
```

Here is the ui: (Elevated Button to add and remove)

```
class CustomElevatedButton extends StatelessWidget {
  final ButtonState buttonState;
  final GlobalKey<FormState> globalKey;
  final TextEditingController controller;

  const CustomElevatedButton({Key? key,
    required this.buttonState,
    required this.globalKey,
    required this.controller})
      : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var blocModel = context.read<StudentHandlerCubit>();
    return ElevatedButton(
      style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
          primary: buttonState == ButtonState.add ? Colors.green : Colors.red),
      onPressed: () {
        if (globalKey.currentState!.validate()) {
          _onPressed(context, buttonState, controller);
          // Navigator.pop(context);
        }
      },
      child: Text(_setText(buttonState)),
    );
  }

  void _onPressed(BuildContext ctx, ButtonState bs,
      TextEditingController cntr) {
    var blocModel = ctx.read<StudentHandlerCubit>();
    bs == ButtonState.add ?
    blocModel.addToBadSts(cntr.text) :
    blocModel.removeFromBadSts(cntr.text);

  }
  String _setText(ButtonState bs) {
    return bs == ButtonState.add ?
    'add' : 'delete';
  }

}
```

And here is the column which I want to show all the names:

```
Column(
                  children: [
                    const Text(header1),
                    const Divider(
                      thickness: 2,
                    ),
                    BlocBuilder<StudentHandlerCubit,
                        StudentHandlerState>(
                        builder: (context, handler) {
                          return Column(
                              children: handler.badSts
                                  .map((e) => Text(e))
                                  .toList());
                        })
                  ],
                ),
```

This codebase does not work.
Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `StudentHandlerState` isn't adding the new list of items to it's internal `badSts` variable so when you emit the new state nothing is updated. Try the following.

```dart
class StudentHandlerState {
  ///Sts = Students
  List<String> badSts;
  StudentHandlerState({required this.badSts});
}
```

Using `this.badSts` assigns the passed in parameter to the `badSts` variable.

Comment: This was the exact issue. Now it works. Thanks.

Comment: Glad to help! Can you please select my answer as accepted?

Comment: Didn't I accept it? I think I did. The green tick is on.

Answer (score 1):

Also I noticed that you are changing the list directly from states. Ideally, states are immutable. Store the values from the state in a separate variable and then add/remove items.

You can do this:

```
void removeFromBadSts(String name){
  final list = state.badSts;
  list.removeWhere((element) => element==name);
  return emit(StudentHandlerState(badSts: list));
}
```

Instead of this:

```
void removeFromBadSts(String name){
  state.badSts.removeWhere((element) => element==name);
  return emit(StudentHandlerState(badSts: state.badSts));
}
```